# Win32 C++ Can "Old Bitmap" Be Reused?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I am wondering when working with HDCs, when I select back the original bitmap, can I use it again? Like...

```
HBITMAP hbmOld;

// FIRST
hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap.hbmItemOverlay);    
Rectangle(hdcMem, 0, 0, MAP_WIDTH*BLOCK_SIZE, MAP_HEIGHT*BLOCK_SIZE); 
SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);

// SECOND
stockBrush = GetStockBrush(BLACK_BRUSH);
hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem2, bitmap.hbmMap);
Rectangle(hdcMem2, 0, 0, bitmap.bmMap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmMap.bmHeight);
SelectObject(hdcMem2, hbmOld);
```

I am wondering if that is valid. It compiles fine and works, but I was wondering if it's bad programming practice to do that?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the code review SE site. A better practice (since you've tagged the question as C++) would be to utilize RAII to avoid the question all together.

Comment: So, your question is if you can reuse the `hbmOld` variable? Answer: *why not?*

Comment: The MSDN entry for `SelectObject` says: _"This function returns the previously selected object of the specified type. An application should always replace a new object with the original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new object."_ So it sounds like what you're doing is the intended course of action.

Comment: @Michael: why don't you make that an answer? ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about. Are you asking if it's okay to reuse a variable?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yes, that seems to be what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems perfectly fine in my opinion.

You could also test for memory leaks just to be 100% sure.

I personally use [*GDIView*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) to do this. The key is for number of handles to be constant in the last column. If you need help with using it leave a comment. I would welcome if others can suggest better or easier to use alternative.

Best regards.